# ipywidgets.VBox not showing once part of function

Tags: python, ipython, ipywidgets

I try to create an interactive dashboard using ipywidgets. (ipywidgets version 7.5.0, python version 3.7.2)

In a single batch of code, the `widgets.VBox()` shows automatically. But once I outsource the statement to a function, the `widgets.VBox()` does not show unless I explicitly wrap it in a `display()` statement. Here is a simple piece of code that works. It shows the slider on top and the number chosen times 5 at the bottom.

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display

def fa(a,b):
    display(a*b)

a = widgets.IntSlider(10)
out = widgets.interactive_output(fa,{'a':a,'b':widgets.fixed(5)})
widgets.VBox([a,out])
```

Once I put the VBox into an output function, nothing is displayed, not even an error message:

```
def fa(a,b):
    display(a*b)

def db(a,b):
   widgets.VBox([a,b])

a = widgets.IntSlider(10)
out = widgets.interactive_output(fa,{'a':a,'b':widgets.fixed(5)})
db(a,out)
```

But once I replace `widgets.VBox([a,b])` in the db() function with `display(widgets.VBox([a,b]))` everything is back to normal.

Sorry, may be a basic question, but what is the system behind this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're working in Notebook, the default behaviour is to print/display the last line of any cell to the output space below. Hence your `widgets.VBox([a,out])` on the last line of your first snippet is actually `display(widgets.VBox([a,out]))` in disguise.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it. Good to know.